# Questions tagged '.aspx' produce Error

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

When clicking on a question tagged [.aspx](/questions/tagged/.aspx), the site produces a 'Page Not Found' error.

Comment: Reproduced in Google Chrome (3.0.196.2). Clicking the [tag:aspx] tag results in a `Page Not Found` error as described.

Comment: temporary solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config/27713#27713

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure this isn't a browswer issue. Looks like the tag (and probably some other special cases) may have to be encoded differently to keep ASP.NET from freaking out.

Comment: I agree. Just being complete in specifying the browser. I suspect that somewhere, the .aspx is causing an incorrect redirection to a non-existant page.

Comment: Agreed, likely a bug than a browser issue

Comment: This also happens with "`.config`"

Comment: It is likely to occur for a variety of different asp.net extensions

Answer (score 2):

Also note this *only* happens with ASP.NET related-extensions (e.g. `.aspx` and `.config`). As in, the `.net` tag and nonexistent `.foo` tag work properly (fixed as per [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/properly-escape-tags-in-search) of mine).

I'd say it's exactly as @TheTXI suggests - ASP.NET thinks it's supposed to be a real page name and barfs. In fact, the `.config` one just brings up a blank page, not even a 404.

Special treatment for the URLs `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.aspx` and `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/.config` might fix it, as well as possibly just not allowing a period in tags. (`.NET` can become `dot-net` or something?)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is attempting to process the actual tag as a page. Any way the moderators can simply remove the . from the tag?