# Cannot search for keyword "Global.asax" in SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, search

Global.asax is name for application wide file in ASP.NET, however i`m unable to search for it in SO if i don't add additional word.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/questions-tagged-.aspx-produce-error

Comment: temporary solution: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config/27713#27713

Answer (score 4):

Go to google and type in:

```
"global.asax" site:stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 3):

The "fix" for this is kind of nuclear, as it would allow access to raw sourcecode and configuration data for the actual website itself.

Thus, I have elected to globally rename these tags to

- web-config
- global-asax

In the future, when the tag blacklist / forced-synonyms is implemented, the dot equivalents will be blacklisted/auto-replaced.

Comment: Six to eight weeks then?