# Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

When I'm trying to see all the questions tagged **web.config** or **app.config** I'm sent to an URL like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config`

which shows an XML parsing error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config
Line Number 1, Column 1:
^
```

It's normal from an ASP.NET point of view, but I would like to see those questions instead.

Since adding another tag like **asp.net** means an URL like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config asp.net`

which solves the problem, but restrict the results, I propose to create an empty, meaningless tag which would not restrict the result set but would avoid the errors.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19622/cannot-search-for-keyword-global-asax-in-so
and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax

Comment: @Shog9: searching is not always a solution.

Comment: also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/questions-tagged-.aspx-produce-error

Comment: @Kip: see my updated answer

Comment: alexandrul: thing is, a solution to this would be good to document as a solution to those other problems. Spreading this discussion around among multiple topics just makes the answers harder to find...

Comment: @Shog9: sorry for not being clear in the first place: searching SO with "web config" in order to find all questions tagged "web.config" doesn't seems to be a nice solution. OTOH, is it possible to move all the answers to a single question in case of duplicates? I've found many nice answers to questions closed as duplicates.

Comment: These tags have been merged and synonyms have been added, so `[app-config]` and `[web-config]` are now the canonical tags.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is re-tagging `web.config` to `web-config`. That's how it should look like in the first place.

Comment: there are 66 questions tagged with .config :(

Comment: It's a moderator task ;)

Comment: the dot is an allowed character in tags, i don't see why the tags should be changed just because the server isn't handling the url properly

Comment: @Kip: Jeff's and your opinion differ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax/23565#23565

Comment: How do you look for a tag to change them if you can't look for them? Example: [tag:.mdf]

Comment: @MPel: Let the mods care about it.

Comment: @MPelletier You can view the questions [using a dummy search parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A0+%5B.mdf%5D).

Comment: @LadybugKiller All the mods did was mark my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The error is still present to this day, by the way.

[.mdf](/questions/tagged/.mdf) turns up empty, [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) works. Go figure.

Comment: As a workaround use `.mdf%20` instead, inserting `%20` in the generated URLs, like: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mdf%20?sort=newest&pagesize=50` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mdf%20?sort=newest&pagesize=50)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a quick rewrite rule for the moment: add " +" at the end of the URL if it ends with `web.config` or `app.config` or the like.

At least the following URL returns the same number of questions:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc +`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc`

and it also works for the following:

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app.config +`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config +`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.aspx +`

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global.asax +`

(but there are no more `globax.asax` tagged questions)

**UPDATE**

Another workaround would be inserting `%20` after the tag name in the generated URLs, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mdf%20?sort=newest&pagesize=50

Comment: If it's implemented, I would like to receive a special badge: fixer :D

Answer (score 3):

.Net 4.0 has a solution for this. Please see http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

Comment: nice and it referenced stack overflow as well :)

Comment: @waffles: now that you work for SO any chance you wanna implement this? :D

Comment: from Phil's article "Please note, that you still can’t request /web.config because that would try to request web.config in the root of your web application and ASP.NET won’t allow that for good reason!" .. we upgraded to .Net 4 and set that flag yet, no dice

Comment: I even tried a rewrite rule and could not get it to work

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a `questions\tagged` sub-folder and remove ".config" from the script mappings in IIS. Not sure if that is secure or not, tho.

Even though the tags *probably* should be `web-config` anyways, I don't think it is a good idea to get an XML parsing error on any reachable URL on the site.  This is easily reachable by searching for `[web.config]`.