# Bug Report - "The resource cannot be found."

Tags: status-completed, 500-server-error, bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

I followed a link form another site to question 77127. However the person had added a full stop the end of the link as below:

[When to throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77127/when-to-throw-an-exception.)

I was not taken to the 404 error page but a server generated "The resource cannot be found." page.

Just thought I should let you know.