# Can't search for "web.config" in the search box

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

searching for "web.config" in the search box yeilds a 404

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config

Answer (score -1):

Try searching for [`[web-config]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-config).