# Why am I unable to open URLs whose last part starts with a dot?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, broken-link

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

Why am I unable to open the following URLs?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.vbproj

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.browser

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mdb

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.mdf

I'm just curious why these links behave strange. It's not about I want to open these, but why these links say `access denied`(Opera), `broken links` in Chrome and similar issues in other browsers?

Comment: Pretty much sounds like status-by-iis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config