# The list of questions tagged '.cs' can't be displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

There are some questions which are tagged with `[.cs]`, but it is not possible to show them. The following URL results in an empty page:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.cs

The same problem exists for other extensions, filenames and paths which are blocked by ASP.NET, ee.g.:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.resx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bin

BTW: I guess the `[.cs]` tag should be replaced with the `[C#]` tag anyway.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a duplicate - will have to search

Comment: @ChrisF: I thought so as well, but wasn't able to find something.

Comment: Wait, ASP.NET is blocking an extension for a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: @TheLQ: with asp.net you can configure handlers for each file-type. By default ".cs" is handled by the HttpForbiddenHandler which denies access to the requested resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, a workaround seems to be to put the tag into brackets:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[.cs]

But this should be done automatically by the system, e.g. when clicking the link for the [.cs] tag on the tags page (https://stackoverflow.com/tags).