# Minor bug: broken "bin" tag on StackOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

This question [Detect 1-time credit cards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679678/how-can-i-detect-1-time-e-credit-cards) on SO is tagged 'bin', presumably for 'bank identification number', but that could easily have been used for something else. However the tag pages and searching for the tag return completely empty pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bin
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bin

as does the hover pop-up for the tag. It's a cross-site problem too

- https://superuser.com/tags/bin
- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bin

I've tried this too with other likely magic filename tag names (e.g. aux, usr, nul, null, com1) but no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the server configuration, [it has also been reported for URLs ending with `.cs`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62699/the-list-of-questions-tagged-cs-cant-be-displayed). [The workaround is to use `[bin]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%5Bbin%5D).

Comment: Oops, yes, that question mentions the bin tag too. Sorry, didn't spot the duplication. However this is still a bug in SO until it generates the `[bin]` URLs I guess.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside to having to use `[bin]` instead to list questions with that tag, I'd say use of `bin` for "bank identification number" is probably wrong and it should be removed (or possibly retagged `cc-bin` or `creditcard-bin`).

Answer (score 2):

We fixed these cases after the upgrade to ASP.Net MVC4 about a year ago - sorry it took so long!