# Is the .java tag allowed?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags with usability problems - app.config and web.config](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27702/tags-with-usability-problems-app-config-and-web-config)

I'm getting a strange bug with one of the synonyms of the [java](/questions/tagged/java) tag, [.java](/questions/tagged/.java).

If you click on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.java) (or in the [list of synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms)) you will go to an invalid webpage.

Is using a tag with a special character like a period allowed?

Comment: That link doesn't break for me.

Comment: You have to click on the `.java` (mind the dot!) link. [tag:.java]

Comment: Oh, ic. It'd be a good idea to redirect those properly.

Comment: Its [tag:.brokd.]...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA ironically that works...

Comment: @BenBrocka weird.... I was expecting it **not** to.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA weird indeed... Is there something special with the word java?

Comment: It seems to happen to any URL ending in `.java`. For example, [this works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124131/foo), but [this doesn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124131/foo.java), even though the question title is only in the URL for SEO purposes, so it should be ignored in both cases. This makes me suspect it might be the web server treating URLs with a `.java` extension differently.

Comment: (`^` is [meta-tag:status-completed] because synonyms were created for the tags, not because IIS was made to behave)

Comment: +1 for @hammar.  [.cs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.cs) is also broken, as I expected.  IIS prevents certain file extensions from being downloaded, .cs (c# file extension) is one of them.  So is [.config](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.config) (web.config files).

Comment: @Won't. That's what I suspected. It also happens to [.dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.dll) and probably a few more.

Answer (score 2):

90% sure its an IIS thing.

> The .NET Framework protects file extensions that should not be directly called by clients by associating them with System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler in Machine.config. The following file extensions are mapped to System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler by default: .asax, .ascx, .config, .cs, .csproj, .vb, .vbproj, .webinfo, .asp, .licx, .resx, and .resources [and more not mentioned [in this article]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648653.aspx)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.asax
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.ascx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.config
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.cs
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.csproj
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.vb
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.vbproj
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.webinfo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.asp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.licx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.resx
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.resources
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.config

From one of the dupe answers, [Phil Haack discusses this in more detail](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx).

Comment: See also: [the default handler list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bya7fh0a.aspx) (which of course includes `.java`)