# Should "global.asa" tag renamed to "global-asa" just like "global-asax"? and also blacklist "global.asa" and "global.asax" tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-block-request

Should [global.asa](/questions/tagged/global.asa) renamed to **[global-asa](/questions/tagged/global-asa)** just like **[global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax)**?

and also blacklist [global.asa](/questions/tagged/global.asa) and [global.asax](/questions/tagged/global.asax) tag?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. If we're going to change those tags, then [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) should become [asp-net](/questions/tagged/asp-net), which I also disagree with.

Hyphens should be used, IMO, to replace spaces, rather than full stops.

Comment: Nope, not all, I literally said only globa.asa and globa.asax, there are tons of valid tags with dots.

Comment: @YOU - yes and my "argument" is that if we change one, we should change *all*, for consistency. Tags lose their usefulness if they're not consistent. So - I guess the question is **why** should global.asax/global.asa be hyphenated? I see no good, compelling reason to.

Comment: sorry, I disagree with the idea about "if we change one, we should change all", Jeff already changed global.aspx to global-aspx [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax/23565#23565) too. I am just mentioning there is another one "global.asa", and should blacklist both for future tagging.

Comment: @YOU, well I disagree. Wouldn't it be boring if we were all the same though =-) Changing a tag because of a technical limitation of the underlying platform is a poor solution.

Comment: @Rob, agree about "because of a technical limitation of the underlying platform is a poor solution", so do you think leaving the broken tag as is better?

Comment: @YOU - I think that in an ideal world, (1) the limitation of the underlying platform should be resolved so that a tag of `global.asa` is valid and then (2) `global-asax` should be returned to `global.asax`. Note, I said "ideal world" as I have no idea how much effort would be involved and if it'd be worth the ROI. Tags need to be consistent & discoverable.