# Problem with the global.asax tag

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does stackoverflow.com crash when i search for “global.asax”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax)

Just saw this problem with the tag "global.asax"
Due to how tags redirects to different page, the global.asax redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/global.asax which causes some nice error page to show up.

I'm just pointing that out. Maybee there's something that sould be done about it

P.S. Some other discussions about the issue, so i know it's not new, but there should be something done about it

[Should "global.asa" tag renamed to "global-asa" just like "global-asax"? and also blacklist "global.asa" and "global.asax" tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87279/should-global-asa-tag-renamed-to-global-asa-just-like-global-asax-and-als)
[Why does stackoverflow.com crash when I search for "global.asax"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax)

Comment: Change it to `global-asax`??

Answer (score 0):

I see absolutely no reason why you would or should be going to the tag wiki page for the [global.asax](/questions/tagged/global.asax) tag, as that tag doesn't even exist. It's a permanent synonym of the more appropriate [global-asax](/questions/tagged/global-asax) tag, [created in response to this very "bug"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22940/why-does-stackoverflow-com-crash-when-i-search-for-global-asax).

Comment: Even though the question is closed, i'd like to point out that if you make a search for the global.asax tag, it does shows a tag global.asax on which you can click and then get to the error page i showed.