# Broken link for ccnet.config

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags

I was about to go and re-tag all the 12 ccnet tags to [cruisecontrol.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cruisecontrol.net) and I got a page not found error on [ccnet.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ccnet.config)!  Gasp!  The horror!

<strike>Could someone then retag the lowly [ccnet.config] to [ccnet-config]? D:</strike> Wait... I can do this!

Comment: This is a known issue- their iis7 configuration flat out refuses to serve anything that looks like a config file. I don't have the link handy for the original, but I'm declining as 'dupe'.

Comment: Re-opening to edit as a retag-request.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/Questions-tagged-.aspx-produce-an-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy of my answer here:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/2930#2930

```
[web.config] => [web-config]
[app.config] => [app-config]
[ccnet.config] => [ccnet-config]
[machine.config] => [machine-config]
[user.config] => [user-config]
```

There was a uservoice request about these tags noting that IIS refuses to serve anything that ends in `.config`.

An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web.config