# My comment flag may not have been handled correctly. Can someone enlighten me as to what happened?

Tags: discussion, flags, meta, disputed-flags

So I came across an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/questions-tagged-aspx-produce-error/12094#12094), screenshot shown below, for this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12092/questions-tagged-aspx-produce-error/12094#12094).

[image: Screenshot of answer]

I felt that this answer really wasn't an answer, so I raised a "it is not an answer" flag, but that flag was disputed, but it's apparent that there are others that feel the same way as I do.  So my question is why was my flag disputed?  I just want to get some perspective on this so I can better understand what really constitutes an answer and what doesn't.  And if this shouldn't have been disputed, well then obviously my flag should be corrected and the answer removed.

Don't know if it's worth mentioning, I have nothing against Jeff Yates, just doing my part to help keep the boards following the established guidelines.

Cheers.

Comment: Disputed doesn't mean "proven wrong" it just means "one person disagreed".

Comment: I seem to remember being one of the 10k users who looked over that flag. There were some agreeing flags some disagreeing flags from 10k users. Remember disputed!=declined

Comment: Yeah, heh, I've gotten a couple disputed flags for VLQ, I don't let them get to me too much.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @RichardTingle.  While I understand we all have differing views, I'm puzzled as to exactly what is in that answer that would lead someone to believe that _is_ a qualified answer to the question that was posted.  I guess that is what is puzzling me.  IMHO, the answer does nothing to resolve the posted issue.

Comment: I also looked at that one, and I agreed with it, but I seem to recall only 1 disagreeing flag.  Disputed means nothing actually, it doesn't count against you, nor does it count towards your helpful count.  I dislike how they are done, but it is how they are handled at the time.

Comment: Oh and for the record, I don't care if I have a disputed flag or not on my record.  Doesn't bother me in the least.  I'm just trying to get persepective on this so that in the future I do raise flags that are as accurate as possible.

Comment: @SlyRaskal I agree with you, and my flag was behind you, as I believe were most of the other flags

Comment: @RichardTingle it's still in the queue - it is now 9 for and 1 against.

Comment: @SlyRaskal the easy explanation is flags on MSO are less cut and dry than on SO.  There is a lot of leeway some users give answers if they are contributing positively to the question, whether or not they actually answer the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003, That makes sense.  I can see that happeneing since MSO is more _discussion_ related.  However my take on an _answer_ is that it should contribute towards a definable resolution.  In this case, the answer simply adds evidence to the posted question, nothing more.  Thanks for your insight, I appreciate it.

Comment: Also, not a big deal, not sure why this is considered a duplicate since I'm asking about perspective about a _specific_ question and answer, not about the general use of 'disputed'.  Oh well, moving on.

Comment: Might be nice if a flag was only disputed if 2+ users disagreed

Comment: That is an excellent idea @RichardTingle!

Comment: @RichardTingle, would you like to create a post outlining that idea? Or would you like for me to do that.  I think that feature would help avoid situations like this one where a _high_ majority agree and there is one outlier, for whatever reason.

Comment: @SlyRaskal I've created a proposal here: [Only consider a flag disputed if 2+ users mark it invalid, or stop showing it at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218214/only-consider-a-flag-disputed-if-2-users-mark-it-invalid-or-stop-showing-it-at)

Comment: Thanks @RichardTingle, I'll take a look at it now.

Comment: @KateGregory, This is the other question you so _graciously_ voted was a duplicate.  This question is not a duplicate of the question you claimed it to be because if you actually followed the _context_ of this post, you'll notice I'm not focusing on the topic of "what is a disputed flag"; instead, I'm asking for assistance and guidance on why I earned a disputed flag for a specific comment that should not have been disputed. You really need to start focusing a little more on the details of a post before you flag. You're not helping when you flag and incorrectly close questions.

Comment: @KateGregory, do the right thing and vote to reopen as this question is _not_ the same as the question you claimed it was a duplicate of.

Comment: @SlyRaskal this sentence "And if this shouldn't have been disputed, well then obviously my flag should be corrected and the answer removed" shows you don't know what a disputed flag means. Therefore the answers to the dupe will give you the answer you seek. Now please leave me be.

Comment: @KateGregory if you are going to assume an _entire post_ is a duplicate based off ONE SENTENCE means that you aren't capable of accurately assessing when to raise a flag.  I'm sorry that you feel annoyed, but the fact of the matter is that you raised a flag incorrectly and you lack the mental capacity to understand and acknowledge that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion (and 8 other people's) your flag was appropriate. The "answer" neither answered the question nor (as is appropriate on meta) provided a new reasoned viewpoint. As such you were correct to flag as not an answer.

One person thought (for whatever reason) that your flag was wrong so it was "disputed" but in this case I would not worry. This does not mean your flag will not be acted upon.

[image: disputed]

Comment: Thanks again for the clarifications and insight.  In the end, I just want to be a more proactive member of SO and MSO, which is the only reason why I posted this question.  We learn by making mistakes which is why I wanted to know _what_ mistake I made, but it sounds like I really didn't, just that someone doesn't fully agree with me, for whatever reason.  Thanks again. Cheers.

Comment: @SlyRaskal - The disputed flag might have come from the fact that the question was a Meta bug report, which is a little different than the standard question and answer style you see elsewhere. I've seen many answers to things like this that describe ways of reproducing the error in question, which could be considered viable responses. I went ahead and converted this to a comment, in any case.